# Laravel sail can't connect to database from host

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I have Ubuntu 20.04 lts installed. I have installed a Laravel project with Laravel sail. All right. After installing laravel I run the migrations with "sail php artisan migrate".

The project works perfectly. I have also installed breeze for authentication. I can create users and log in. The problem comes that from Ubuntu it does not seem to be able to connect to that database.
Here you can see my configuration of my docker-compose.yml file. I have changed the mysql port to 3307 because it generated conflict:

```
mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
        - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
```

And this is my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=example_app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

In Ubuntu I have installed mysql-server and tableplus. I open the console and open tableplus as root

```
jorge@jorge-VirtualBox:~$ sudo su
[sudo] contraseña para jorge: 
root@jorge-VirtualBox:/home/jorge# tableplus
```

And once I open tableplus as root I configure the data to connect.

[tableplus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alnj5.png)

It tells me that the database does not exist. I do not know what to do.
I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Please do not use pictures for what should be code in your question. Leave pictures for things that cannot be described in words and/or copy pasted verbatim in your question. Related: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Since i had a similar problem, and also changed my default laravel sail port to 3307. This configuration finally works for me:

.env file (set your your_project_name):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=your_project_name
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

docker-compose.yml (changed ports and added MYSQL_TCP_PORT definition)

```
mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3307'
    environment:
        MYSQL_TCP_PORT: '${DB_PORT}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
        - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I leave the solution here in case it can help someone.
Apparently TablePlus is in a beta version on Linux. I have downloaded Workbench for Ubuntu. After I have configured the connection as in the image that I attach. There I have been able to see the Laravel database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UK0Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've configured with the following params:

```
HOST: 127.0.0.1
USER: root
PSW:  your pwd here
DB:   db_name
```